# add sub collection inside a collection in firebase

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

**So my goal here is to create a subcollection inside a collection in firebase**

```
const Courses = () => {
    // add course func
        const [data, setData] = useState({})
    
        const handleinput = e =>{
        const id = e.target.id;
        const value = e.target.value;
        setData({...data, [id]:value})
    }
    console.log(data);
```

> i want the subcollection to be anything the user insputs which is (why i used data.newcourse) but it instead creates a doc inside the main collection

```
    //add course to data base
    const handleadd = async (e) =>{
        e.preventDefault()
        try{
          addDoc(collection(db , "Courses", "", data.newcourse ), {
            ...data,
            timestamp: serverTimestamp(),
            
          });
          alert("Course added succesfully")
        }
        catch (e){
          console.log(e.message)
        }
      }



return (
    <div className='main'>
        <Navbar/>
        <div className="list-header">
            <div className="rheader">
                <h1>Courses</h1>
            </div>
            <div className="addr">
                <div className="addrheader">
                    <h3>Add Course</h3>
                </div>
                <form 
                className='rinputs'>
                    <input
                    id='newcourse'
                    onChange={handleinput}
                    className='Rinputs'
                    placeholder='Enter Course Name'
                    type="text" />
                    <button
                    onClick={handleadd}
                    className='addbtn'>
              <BsPlusCircleFill size={30}/>
              ADD
              </button>
```

**im new to firebase!**
**Will be thankful if helped**

Answer (score 1):

The `collectionID` and `subCollection` should not be an empty string.

```
addDoc(collection(db , "Courses", "collectionID", data.newcourse )
```

You need to make sure that the user's input is valid to direct to subCollection not an empty string.

Sample Code (empty string):

```
const docRef = await addDoc(collection(db, "test", "wQMh3almCwlrMaZkyQgO", ""),
        {      
          test: "Test",
        }
      );
```

Sample Output (empty string):
[image]

Sample Code (valid string):

```
const test = "hello";
const docRef = await addDoc(collection(db, "test", "wQMh3almCwlrMaZkyQgO", test),
        {      
          test: "Test",
        }
      );
```

Sample Output (valid string):
[image]

Comment: it worked! arigato

Comment: btw how can i fetch this sub colleection?
const [getCourse, setGetcourse] = useState([]);
useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      let list = [];
      try {
        const querySnapshot = await getDocs(collection(db, "Courses"));
        querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
          list.push({ id: doc.id, ...doc.data() });
        });
        setGetcourse(list);
        console.log(list);
      } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
      }
    };
    fetchData();
},[])
console.log(getCourse);
i read somwhere that there is getCollections() but doesn't wrk

Comment: You may want to accept my answer. and for your question that is another question you should post for that scenario. Thanks